# How to calculate an elliptic integral (from geodesics equations of torus)!

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, riemann-surfaces

- The exercice that my professor gave me :
- Calculate the geodesics equations of a torus with a lagrangien equation, i did the calculation in the final i got this elliptic integral,he asked us to calculate it. I m thinking of changing variable but i don t know which one exactly!!

  $\int\frac{1}{(2+\cos(v))\sqrt{((2+\cos(v))^2-\alpha^2)}} dv$

  A hint can help!

thank you for help! :)

Comment: Don't you need a Riemaniann manifold structure, a metric to speak of geodesics ? The flat metric on $\Bbb{C/(uZ+vZ)}$ gives that the geodesics are the line segments $\gamma(t)=a+bt+\Bbb{uZ+vZ}$. Or maybe you meant on a complex elliptic curve ? If so it is $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\gamma(h)-\gamma(0)}{h}$ where $-$ is the group law of the elliptic curve, $\gamma(t)=(\wp(a+bt),\wp'(a+bt))$.

Comment: @reuns  We just started the Riemaniann geometry so we did not study a lot of it  ...i don t know if i can just resolve this integral with changing variable in simple way if it s possible. Thank you for help

Comment: Did you mean the geodesics for the group law invariant metric on a complex elliptic curve $E:y^2=4x^3-ax-b$ yes or no ? If so I don't think there is any simpler formula than $\gamma(t)=(\wp(a+bt),\wp'(a+bt))$ where $\wp$ is the Weierstrass function giving an isomorphism  $\Bbb{C/uZ+vZ}\to E, z\to (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$.

Comment: @reuns i m lost ...No we didn't talk about this ...i think we did something very simple, i really want to show in images what we did. i don t know if it s possible!